# regex not matching two delimiter chars

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a long string that contains url, title, description like this:

```
||url:foo||title:Books|Pencils||description:my description||
```

Data is always starting and ending with `||`

How can I match that title (`Books|Pencils`) which **might** include an `|` (as in above sample) but not two `||` ?

I tried rules like these (using php preg_match):

`#\|\|title:(.*)([\|\|])(.*)#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess,

```
(?<=\|\|title:).*?(?=\|\|)
```

might simply do that.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/sj0VYv/1/)

and if you want to get the other two,

```
(?<=\|\|\burl:|\btitle:|\bdescription:).*?(?=\|\|)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/IxKf8F/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?<=\|\|\burl:|\btitle:|\bdescription:).*?(?=\|\|)/m';
$str = '||url:foo||title:Books|Pencils||description:my description||';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "Books|Pencils"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "my description"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IxKf8F/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/IxKf8F/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Comment: Thanks, I wanted some details but the top right panel does just that :)